# Javascript fullcalendar version 1.6.4 annotation is not working as it is working in 1.5.4 version

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-1

```
$("#calendarDiv").fullCalendar({
      header: {
          left: 'prev,today,next,agendaWeek,month',
          right: 'title'
      },
      customButtons: {
        myCustomButton: {
          text: 'custom!',
          click: function() {
            alert('clicked the custom button!');
          }
        }
      },
      columnFormat: {
          week: "ddd - d",
          viewRender: function(view, element) {
              
          }
      },
      titleFormat: {
          week: "MMMM yyyy"
      },
      firstHour: 9,
      firstDay: 1,
      height: 947,
      defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      editable: false,
      selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,
      slotMinutes: 15,
      allDaySlot: false,
      select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        let modifyParam = self.autoSelectStartTimeEndTime({'start': start,'end': end});
        self.commonService.setCalendarParam({'start': modifyParam.start,'end': modifyParam.end});
        self.preSelectCheck({'start': start,'end': end,'flag': 0});
      },
      eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        if (calEvent.title != 'Break Time') {
          self.commonService.setCalendarParam(calEvent);
          self.openTimesheetForm(calEvent)
        }
      },
      events: function(start, end, callback) { 
        self.getCalendarEvents({'start': start,'end': end},callback);
      },
      annotations: this.annotationData
});
```

annotation is not showing on calendar, is there any other way to showing it ?

I tried upgrading fullcalendar version 1.5.4 to 1.6.4 but only annotation is not working

Comment: There is no `annotations` option in any version of fullCalendar, and certainly not in v1 - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1#toc. Is that feature the result of some kind of add-on or plugin, or a fork of fullCalendar that you were using?? And why are you still using such an ancient fullCalendar version anyway? The current version is v6 and it has many more features, bug fixes and performance improvements.